# Problems with finding a "Shared" directory in isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7.8

When I use the following code:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

string[] listDirectories = appStorage.GetDirectoryNames();
```

I pull up a directory called "Shared", is there any easy way to ignore this directory, or will I have to define parameters in `GetDirectoryNames()`?

And also, what is/can the Shared folder be used for?

Comment: What do you mean with ignoring the directory? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove it from the results:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var listDirectories = appStorage.GetDirectoryNames().Where(l => l != "Shared");
```

It can be used for example when generating custom images as you live tiles, the images must be stored in this directory.